# Modal de Imagem só funciona com a primeira

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um modal de imagens mas só funciona com a primeira, alguém pode me ajudar ? veja o modal aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/pnavtmcx/

Answer (score 8):

O problema é que as duas imagens possuem o mesmo ID e é um atributo que deve ser único. Uma opção é criar um atributo qualquer e selecionar os elementos por [querySelector](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp):

Ficaria assim:

HTML

```
<img id="myImg1" get-img alt="Texto qualquer" width="300" height="200">
<img id="myImg2" get-img alt="Texto qualquer" width="300" height="200">
```

Javascript:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('[get-img]');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

for (var i = 0 ; i < imgs.length ; i++){
  imgs[i].onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
}
```

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/pnavtmcx/6/

Comment: Só faltou ajustar o css: https://jsfiddle.net/kdk9ztyt/

Comment: Valeu @IvanFerrer, ajustei!

Answer (score 4):

O id é um atributo que deve ser atribuído a apenas um elemento, mude o seu código para usar como 'target' do javascript a classe da imagem.

As classes são usadas justamente para poder interagir com mais de um elemento no DOM.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
```

Algo assim, no X ficam todos os elementos com aquela classe em um array, que começa com o index 0.