# Pegar value ou name do button com JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, value

Alguém sabe como eu poderia pegar o `value` de um `button` usando *JQuery*?

O que quero fazer é usar este `value` em uma `textarea`, então não precisa ser necessariamente o `value`, o `name` também serviria.

Quero que function assim:
Tenho uma listagem com vários `Buttons`, e ao lado uma `textarea`. O que quero é quando clicado no botao (cada um com seu `value` ou `name`) apareça o `value`/`name` na `textarea` ao lado.
E o que não estou conseguindo é pegar o `value`/`name` do `button` ao clicar no botao.

Pra isso eu ja tenho cada botao com mesmo `id`, e no JQuery utilizar a função `.click()`

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Grato desde ja!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode obter as propriedades do botão diretamente no `click`. Algumas propriedades é possível com `attr` ou `prop`. E depois atribuir ao `textarea`.

**Exemplo**

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var valor = $(this).val();
  var nome = $(this).attr('name');
  $('#area').val(valor + ' ' + nome)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="1" name="um">Um</button>
<button value="2" name="dois">Dois</button>
<button value="3" name="tres">Tres</button>
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
```

**Obs:** Não é possível usar o [mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166358/modal-de-imagem-s%C3%B3-funciona-com-a-primeira/166359#166359) *id* em vários elementos.

Comment: Deu certo aqui @Lucas Costa. Eu estava tentando pegar o botao com o id.
Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Tem essa forma que é bem simples.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>CLIQUE NO BOTAO E RETORNA O VALOR EM UMA DIV</p>

<button id="meuBotao" value="Teste do Botão" onclick="retornaValor()">Teste</button>

<div id="demonstracao"></div>

<script>
function retornaValor() {
  var x = document.getElementById("meuBotao").value;
  document.getElementById("demonstracao").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```