# Selecionar conteudo da linha da tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Fala pessoal tudo bem?

tenho um aplicação HTML,PHP,Jquery, bootstrap e numa mesma tela tenho duas tabelas a primeira de clientes que trago via AJAX quando digito o nome do cliente no campo "buscar", isso me retorna uma tabela com nome,cpf e um botão "selecionar cliente", 
esse botão selecionar cliente quando é gerado por "while" já insiro no seu atributo "value" o id do cliente para quando eu seleciona-lo saber de quem estou falando. porem quando seleciono o cliente na lista, ele traz o "value" como indefinido, preciso selecionar o cliente para depois na segunda tabela da mesma tela selecionar somente os produtos comprados por ele filtrando pelo seu ID.

pensei em fazer como nesta resposta aqui [Pegar value ou name do button com JQuery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217979/pegar-value-ou-name-do-button-com-jquery)

mas ele traz o "value" como indefinido, quando clico com o botão direto do mouse e inspeciono, ele está com o "value" correto, mas quando clico não preenche meu Textarea.

AJAX:

```
function CriaRequest() {
 try{
     request = new XMLHttpRequest();        
 }catch (IEAtual){

     try{
         request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");       
     }catch(IEAntigo){

         try{
             request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");          
         }catch(falha){
             request = false;
         }
     }
 }

 if (!request) 
     alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
 else
     return request;
}



function getDadosCliente() {

 var nome   = document.getElementById("buscarcliente").value;
 var result = document.getElementById("ResultadoCliente");
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();

 result.innerHTML = '<img src="../img/loading.gif"/>';

 xmlreq.open("GET", "buscarcliente.php?buscarcliente=" + nome, true);

 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){

     if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {

         if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
             result.innerHTML = xmlreq.responseText;
         }else{
             result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
         }
     }
 };
 xmlreq.send(null);
 }
```

buscarcliente.php(o que o AJAX chama):

```
<?php


if (isset($_GET["buscarcliente"])) {
$nome = $_GET["buscarcliente"];
if (empty($nome)) {
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM clientes");
} else {
    $nome .= "%";
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nomeCliente LIKE '$nome'");
}
sleep(1);

    $dados = mysqli_query($conecta,$query);
    // transforma os dados em um array
    $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados);
    // calcula quantos dados retornaram
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($dados);
    $cont = mysqli_affected_rows($conecta);


 if($cont > 0) {


    $tabela = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class='text-center info'>NOME</th>
                        <th class='text-center info'>CPF/CNPJ</th>
                        <th class='text-center info'>AÇÃO</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>";
    $return = "$tabela";
     do{
        $return.= "<td>" . utf8_encode($linha['nomeCliente']) . "</td>";
        $return.= "<td>" . utf8_encode($linha['cpfcnpj']) . "</td>";
        $return.= "<td class='text-center'><a onclick='selecaoCliente()' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' value=".$linha['idCliente']."><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span></a></td>";
        $return.= "</tr>";
    }        while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados)) ;

    echo $return.="</tbody></table>";
} else {
    echo "Não foram encontrados registros!";
}
}


 ?>
```

no HTML so tenho o input buscar, a div de resultado, o textarea, e o segundo campo buscar com o o segundo div de resultado.

Comment: Alexandre, poste o código para podermos lhe auxiliar.

Comment: editei a pergunta e coloquei o codigo

Comment: Seria interessante postar o `HTML` também. Quanto mais informação, mais fácil da sua pergunta receber atenção.

Comment: Faltou colocar o código da função `selecaoCliente()` para ver como está sendo feito.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de fazer isso mais simples, seria usando o axios, um exemplo seria assim:

```
var nome   = "itasouza";

//usando o  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
axios.get("https://api.github.com/users/"+ nome)
.then(function(response){
    //esperando a resposta para fazer alguma coisa
    console.log(response);
    console.log("login :" + response.data.login);
    console.log("id : " + response.data.id);
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
})
```